# New Jobs Bug: Fill out your CV - Strange

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The actual bug - deleting a tag under "Tech you want to work with" destroys the layout.

Before:

[image: Before deleting a tag]

After:

[image: after delete]

BTW: I detest the fact that I MUST enter a 200-character statement and add all that other stuff up front before I can even see what I am getting. Surely these shoul be editable fields which only *go-live* when all is ready.

Why are we falling back into the dark-ages of modal dialogs!!!